# Windows 10 pro will not accept group policy from 2012 r2 AD DC

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a win 2012 r2 AD controller that windows 2012 r2 servers can join and group policy is correctly applied to.... however after joining a Windows 10 desktop the same group policy does not work. These systems can join the domain but will not apply the group policy. I get  an error code 1326 when looking through the report generated with GPRESULT /H GPReport.html. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded and installed the Windows 10 Group Policy Templates?

These are available here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257

The guide to installing them is available here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530196.aspx

Also is your Windows 10 PC in the same Active Directory container the group Policy is applied to? If not it will need to be moved there for the policies to be applied.

The error code does seem to refer to issues logging in with the computer account, which could mean that there were problems with it joining the domian correctly. Have you tried removing the PC from the domain, deleting it from AD, and re-adding it?